# How to convert list class to template so that it work with any data?

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

How to convert list class to templated linked class so that it work with any data. Below is a class that works with integers. I wanna convert it to templated class so that it works with any data type

```
#ifndef _INTLIST_H_
#define _INTLIST_H_
#include <iostream>
class IntListNode
{
    protected:
        int value;
    public:
        IntListNode* nxt;
        IntListNode(int = 0, IntListNode* = NULL);
        IntListNode(const IntListNode&);
        IntListNode& operator=(const IntListNode&);
        int val() const;
        void val(int);
        IntListNode* next() const;
};

class IntList
{
    protected:
        IntListNode* nhead;
        IntListNode* tail;
        int csize;
    public:
        IntList();
        IntList(const IntList&);
        IntList& operator=(const IntList&);
        int size() const;
        IntListNode* head() const;
        void push(int);
        void pop();
        void clear();
        ~IntList();
};

#endif
```

This is what i have done

```
#ifndef _INTLIST_H_
#define _INTLIST_H_
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class IntListNode
{
    protected:
        T value;
    public:
        IntListNode* nxt;
        IntListNode(int = 0, IntListNode* = NULL);
        IntListNode(const IntListNode&);
        IntListNode& operator=(const IntListNode&);
        T val() const;
        void val(T);
        IntListNode* next() const;
};


template <class T>
class IntList
{
    protected:
        IntListNode<T> nhead;
        IntListNode<T>tail;
        int csize;
    public:
        IntList();
        IntList(const IntList&);
        IntList& operator=(const IntList&);
        int size() const;
        IntListNode* head() const;
        void push(T);
        void pop();
        void clear();
        ~IntList();
};

#endif
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @carlosdc i am not sure how to use template in this case because i am using IntListNode class inside IntList class

Comment: I think that you would make better use of Stack Overflow as a resource and obtain better answers if you (1) show what you have tried and (2) ask specifically about what is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `IntLisNode` to `ListNode` and make it a class template.
2. Change `IntLis` to `List` and make it a class template. Use `ListNode<T>` in `List` instead of `IntListNode`.
3. Replace use of `int` by `T` in some places and by `T const&` in the function signatures.

Here's a quick makeover.

```
#ifndef _LIST_H_
#define _LIST_H_
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class ListNode
{
    protected:
        T value;
    public:
        ListNode* nxt;
        ListNode(T const& in, ListNode* = NULL);
        ListNode(const ListNode&);
        ListNode& operator=(const ListNode&);
        T const& val() const;
        void val(T const&);
        ListNode* next() const;
};

template <typename T>
class List
{
    protected:
        ListNode<T>* nhead;
        ListNode<T>* tail;
        int csize;
    public:
        List();
        List(const List&);
        List& operator=(const List&);
        int size() const;
        ListNode<T>* head() const;
        void push(T const& val);
        void pop();
        void clear();
        ~List();
};
```

Comment: So this will change in .cpp file IntListNode::IntListNode(int d, IntListNode* a){value = d;nxt = a;}

Comment: Yes, you will need to change the function implementations to use the new class template.  Also, you will have to move the implementations to a .h file too (could be the same file).

Comment: so if i put in different .cpp file it would look like  template <class T> IntListNode<T>::IntListNode(T d, IntListNode* a){value = d;nxt = a;} Right ?

Comment: No. It will be `template <typename T> ListNode<T>::ListNode<T const& d, ListNode* a) { value = d; nxt = a;}`. No, you can't put it in a .cpp file. It has to be in a `.h` or `.hpp` file.

Comment: @Nakib Glad I was able to help.